# All-in-One Event Calendar: How do you display the event date?

Tags: calendar, plugin-events-calendar

I want something like this to show up:
Jan
29
Mon
2-9 pm

I can't use `<?php echo $event->get_timespan_html(); ?>` as it would display something like "July 13, 2013 @ 1:00 pm – 3:00 pm."

I also tried

```
<?php echo date_i18n( 'M', $timestamp, true ) ?>
<?php echo date_i18n( 'j', $timestamp, true ) ?>
<?php echo date_i18n( 'D', $timestamp, true ) ?>
<?php echo $event->get_start_time(); ?> – <?php echo $event->get_end_time(); ?>
```

but for some reason it only displays Jan 1 Thu 1:00 pm – 3:00 pm instead of the correct event information.

Help?

Comment: How are you assigning `$timestamp`?

Comment: Sorry I'm a php newbie so I'm not sure what you mean, heh. I just found this after Google search and can't find anything else. If you want, here's the link to the original Wordpress forum post that I found the code from http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-all-in-one-event-calendar-localization-on-widget?replies=3

Answer (score -2):

Finally solved it!

Go [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90939/all-in-one-event-calendar-custom-query-getting-each-event-instance) and skip to the answer. So happy the problem is solved :)